# fadeIn each list value with delay

Tags: jquery

I want to fade in each element in my array with a slight delay from the preceding element so they dont all fade in at the same time.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var arr = ['<img src="images/1.jpg" />', '<img src="images/1.jpg" />', '<img src="images/1.jpg" />', '<img src="images/1.jpg" />', '<img src="images/1.jpg" />'];
    $(function() {
        $.each(arr, function() {
            $('<li style="padding-right:30px;padding-bottom:40px;">' + this + '</li>').appendTo(".project_images").fadeIn(500);
        });
    });
})
```

Can anyone advise?

Thanks in advance

Wayne

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the callback argument on fadeIn to run a piece of code once the animation is complete.

In this example, I use 'shift' on the array to pop an item from the front of it. Then I add this item, ensure it's initially hidden and fade it in. If there are any more items in the array, it will call itself.

```
$(function() {
    var arr = ["hello", "item", "item2", "another"];

    function fadeInNextItem(el,parent) {
        var item = el.shift();
        if (item) {
            $('<li style="padding-right:30px;padding-bottom:40px;">' + item + '</li>')
               .appendTo(parent)
               .hide()
               .fadeIn(500, fadeInNextItem);
        }
    }

    fadeInNextItem(arr,'.project_images');

})
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/zandA/

Comment: +1 Yup; very similar to [mine](http://jsfiddle.net/gothick/7Sy8j/2/), but you got there faster :)

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I was after Thanks Jonathon

Comment: @Matt I wish I thought of using place kitten! You'd have had my vote just for that :)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally this should be done on the callback of `fadeIn`. A simple hack will be to set delay according to index like this.

```
$.each(arr, function(i) {
    $('<li style="padding-right:30px;padding-bottom:40px;">' + this + '</li>')
        .appendTo(".project_images")
        .hide()
        .delay(i*500)
        .fadeIn(500);
});
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/gothick/GcyVK/1/

Comment: This will start them all off fading in at the same time, it's just that the later ones will be slower to fade in - admittedly, still a nice effect :)

Comment: yep. as i said its just a hack. :)

Comment: Though it only needs a [very minor hack](http://jsfiddle.net/gothick/GcyVK/1/) to create the desired effect, adding a delay() instead of bumping up the fade-in each time...

Comment: @Matt Gibson: very true. completely forget about delay. Can I borrow your code?

Comment: I complete forgot about `delay`. Fantastic :)

Answer (score 1):

This shows how to loop through a set of elements. It could be applied to an array easily (Sorry I'm in a rush and cant finish it right now) It might help point you in the right direction.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/X8swk/2/

```
<div id="Box1" class="hidden">Test 1</div>
<div id="Box2" class="hidden">Test 2</div>
<div id="Box3" class="hidden">Test 3</div>
<div id="Box4" class="hidden">Test 4</div>

.hidden {
    display:none;
}


var SetToShow = $(".hidden");

ShowBoxs(SetToShow, 0);


function ShowBoxs(BoxSet, i) {
    $(BoxSet[i]).fadeIn("slow", function(){
        i++;
        ShowBox(BoxSet, i);
    });
}
```

Basically it fades in the element and when done it calls its self again with the next index.

Comment: Thanks Henry for the tip on answering, I tried a few times to use the arrow to add points or whatever it is to the answer but it prompts me to login again! Think i need more credit points or something not too sure but I only discovered the tick mark in one of my last posts!! Silly of me really!

Comment: No problem at all :) It just helps to get replies faster if people think they will get points for their effort and obviously quick replies benefit you. Glad you've sorted it out :)

Answer (score 0):

.fadeIn() has an optional callback argument which allows you to execute a function when the fadeIn animation is complete. You can use this to fadeIn elements in order:

```
$("#img1").fadeIn("slow", function(){
  $("#img2").fadeIn("slow", function(){
    $("#img3").fadeIn("slow", function(){
      $("#img4").fadeIn("slow");
    });
  });
});
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply JJ, it seems a bit long winded though if I had a large array?

Comment: Well you can enhance it to be more generic. Make the callback use .next() to select the next img element and call .fadeIn(). This will make a recursive fadeIn effect (one img calls the next).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `index` as a counter and `setTimeout`, something like...

```
// TESTED
$(document).ready(function() {
    var arr = ['<img src="images/1.jpg" />', '<img src="images/1.jpg" />', '<img src="images/1.jpg" />', '<img src="images/1.jpg" />', '<img src="images/1.jpg" />'];
    $(function() {
        $.each(arr, function(index) {
            var counter = index * 500;
            setTimeout(function(){$('<li style="padding-right:30px;padding-bottom:40px;">' + arr[index] + '</li>').appendTo(".project_images").fadeIn(500);},counter);
        });
    });
});
```

[Test here](http://jsfiddle.net/3jYN5/)

Comment: Cheers Toopay, the output from each listed value of your suggested code prints [OBJECT DOMWINDOW], do you know how I would go about fixing that?

Comment: @Toopay The function in the timeout will be in the context of the window so `this` represents that. You'll need to set a variable before the timeout and use it in place of the `this`

Comment: Yes, i edited above code should fine now. Thats why previously i noted above code as `UNTESTED`

Comment: This ends up being similar to @naveen's current answer, though he/I used the jQuery delay() method to keep things a bit more concise.